# How to keep odd/even elements left or right upon jQuery remove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have this code:

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{width:400px}
.wrapper div{width:200px}

.odd {float:left}
.even {float:right}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>Odd</div>
    <div>Even</div>
    <div>Odd</div>
    <div>Even</div>
    <div>Odd</div>
    <div>Even</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.wrapper').each(function() {
    var $children = $(this).children(),
    $item;
    $children.each(function(i) {
       $item = $(this).addClass(i % 2 === 0 ? 'odd' : 'even')
    });
});
```

Which works as you'd expect.

My question is, how can I keep the `.odd` elements `left` and the `.even` elements `right` when one is removed by jQuery `.remove()` ?

I've tried this, but it obviously doesn't work:

```
$('.wrapper div').click(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('odd');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('even');

        $('.wrapper').each(function() {
            var $children = $(this).children(),
            $item;
            $children.each(function(i) {
                $item = $(this)
                .addClass(i % 2 === 0 ? 'odd' : 'even')
            });
        });

    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Any suggestions really appreciated!

Comment: Add them to separate container `<div>`s.

Comment: The child <div> s are comments, which are added dynamically. Don't suppose there is perhaps a function whereby each floated container would show the respective nth-child elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [even](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) and [odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) selectors. **Updated:** If you use `position` property, elements won't float over when others removed.

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/edVh6/9/)

**jQuery:**

```
var boxHeight = $(".wrapper div").height();
$(".wrapper div:even").addClass("even");
$(".wrapper div:odd").addClass("odd");
//this initualise once after page load, so values won't change/update on click

$(".wrapper div").each(function(i){
    if ( i === 2 || i === 3 ) { $(this).css('top', boxHeight +'px'); }
    if ( i === 4 || i === 5 ) { $(this).css('top', 2*boxHeight +'px'); }
});

$(".wrapper div").click(function(){ $(this).remove(); });
```

**css:**

```
.wrapper{position:relative;left:0;top:0;}
    .wrapper div{position:absolute;top:0;}
        .wrapper .even{ left:0; }
        .wrapper .odd{ right:0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need to keep each nth-child floated left or right when one is removed.
fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/edVh6/1/)

Alas, I'm beginning to think this is only possible with floated containers (which I can't use) :(

Comment: thanks so much for the help but if either of the top two even's were to be removed then an odd will float over

Comment: @user1871949 Than you need to use position property, answer updated. There is one more way for preventing float over issue: You need to dublicate wrapper and seperate even and odd div in wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid javasscript and use the CSS nth-child

```
div.wrapper:nth-child(odd) {
    color: red;
    float:right;
}
div.wrapper:nth-child(even) {
    color:blue;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: This is a good way too but note that IE8 and lower versions doesn't support it.